# Matrix multiplication implement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I implement simple matrix multiplication in javascript by **for**

```
var multipliction = function(matrixA,matrixB){
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0;i < matrixA.length;i++){
        result.push(new Array());
        for (var j = 0;j < matrixB.length;j++)
                result[i].push(0);
    }

    for (var i = 0;i < matrixA.length;i++)
        for (var j = 0;j < matrixA[i].length ;j++)
            for(var k = 0;k < matrixB[j].length;k++)
                result[i][j] += matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
    return result;
};
```

but I think it runs async ,so if some part takes long to execute,it will jump to next and result is't trusted, what's the way to be sure that above code run synchronously ?

Comment: Your code snippet is fully synchronous. What makes you think that (parts of) your function runs asynchronously?

Comment: 2 blocks of code,if create new Array takes longer than calculating result.for example result[10][10]+= runs but it's undefined.

Comment: JavaScript code generally runs in a single thread, so concurrency issues won't happen. Go through your code, step-by-step, and think "What am I doing here? What would happen with the `result` array?". You will quickly figure out that there's something wrong at first loop.

Comment: Oh,sry,it's just for test:)